# CommandError: ngrok tunnel took too long to connect

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am facing error in my project via VS Code. while starting the React Native Expo project. I use `npx expo start --tunnel` command. After that this error occurs `CommandError: ngrok tunnel took too long to connect.`
Anyone know how to solve this issue?

I also tried installing `ngrok` still it's not working, I even installed tunnel also in React Native.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the public firewall if you're using a Windows device. This worked for me.

Make sure in your package.json file, have `expo start --tunnel` instead of `expo start`. Run it with `npm run start` and it should work.